# How to use "Async & Await" here

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to await the other processes until "Getting Username from firestore and putting it into postMap" How can I make them wait? Because if they don't wait username can not uploading to firestore and that cause some problems. I know I can use "Async & Await" method but how? (You can look at the comment lines that I created and see which processes are happening there.)

```
if(selectedPicture != null){
    imageReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener {
        val uploadPictureReference = storage.reference.child("images").child(imageName)
        uploadPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            val downloadUrl = it.toString()
            if(auth.currentUser != null){
                val postMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
                postMap.put("downloadUrl",downloadUrl)
                postMap.put("userEmail",auth.currentUser!!.email!!)
                postMap.put("comment",binding.uploadCommentText.text.toString())
                postMap.put("date",Timestamp.now())

                //Get Username from firestore and put it into postMap
                db.collection("UserDetails").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                    if(error!=null){
                        Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }else{
                        if(value!=null){
                            if(!value.isEmpty){
                                val documents = value.documents
                                for (document in documents){
                                    val username = document.get("username")as String
                                    //Put username into postMap
                                    postMap.put("username",username) as String

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //upload postmap to firestore
                firestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).addOnSuccessListener {
                    finish()

                }.addOnFailureListener{
                    Toast.makeText(this,it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

        }

    }.addOnFailureListener{
        Toast.makeText(this,it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `async/await` in Kotlin/Java. You can use suspend functions that are provided by Kotlin coroutines. However, if you never used coroutines then you should first learn and only then try to use them. Converting the code to coroutines without good understanding of the topic will probably cause you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Oh thank you very much man. I'm following a course and the next section is about coroutines. But are there any other ways to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know 100 % what you are trying to achieve, but by adding the firebase-ktx library, you can use `.await()` to get your values inside a coroutine.

```
// Returns true when everything was successful, or false if not
suspend fun getUserNameAndPutInPostMap(selectedPicture: File?): Boolean {
      try {
         if (selectedPicture == null || auth.currentUser == null) return

         imageReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).await()

         val downloadUrl = storage.reference.child("images").child(imageName).downloadUrl.await().toString()

         val userName = db.collection("UserDetails").get("username").await().toString()

         val postMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>().apply {
             put("downloadUrl", downloadUrl)
             put("userEmail", auth.currentUser!!.email!!)
             put("comment",binding.uploadCommentText.text.toString())
             put("date",Timestamp.now())
             put("username",username)
         }

         firestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).await()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
         return false
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `firestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap)` will need to be inside the `addSnapshotListener` callback, right after you populate the `postMap` with `postMap.put("username",username) as String`.

```
db.collection("UserDetails").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
    if(error!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }else{
        if(value!=null){
            if(!value.isEmpty){
                val documents = value.documents
                for (document in documents){
                    val username = document.get("username")as String
                    //Put username into postMap
                    postMap.put("username",username) as String

                    //upload postmap to firestore
                    firestore.collection("Posts").add(postMap).addOnSuccessListener {
                        finish()
                    }.addOnFailureListener{
                        Toast.makeText(this,it.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I also recommend converting the `onSnapshot` to a `get().addOnCompleteListener(` call, because I'm pretty sure only mean to [read the user data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).